# Adding br tag in innerHTML between text and image

Tags: javascript

In my javascript program I have created div and added image and some hardcoded text in div by using innerHTML. But I am trying to add dynamic br tag between text and image. First text should be displayed then want to line break and then image should be displayed. So created br and added but somehow it doesn't work. Can anyone correct me ?

code:

```js
function useInnerHTML() {

  var movieText2 = prompt("One of my favourite movies");

  var textNode = document.createTextNode(movieText2);
  ele.appendChild(textNode);
  document.body.appendChild(ele);

  var newDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  newDiv2.className = "green";

  var pic = "A picture is worth a thousand words";
  var text2 = '<img src=\'https://i.stack.imgur.com/meXYL.png\'>';

  newDiv2.innerHTML = pic + text2;

  document.body.appendChild(newDiv2);
  document.body.appendChild(br);

}

useInnerHTML();
```

```css
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.green {
  background-color: #71e887;
}
```

**my output:**

![output][1]

Comment: Have you tried `pic = "A picture is worth a thousand words <br>";` ???

Comment: If you want to know why it doesn't work - you're adding it after your whole content, not between those elements

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you so much. now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
pic = "A picture is worth a thousand words <br>";
```

since by using `.innerHTML` the `<br>` tag will not be escaped and actually embedded into the HTML as a breakline Element.

---

Or

#### Use Template strings and `insertAdjacentHTML`

```js
function addNewMovie() {

  var movieName = prompt("One of my favourite movies").trim(); // Trim it!
  if(!movieName) return;                                       // do nothing if empty!

  var movieTemplate = `
    <div class="movie">
      <h1>${movieName}</h1>
      <div class="green">
        A picture is worth a thousand words<br>
        <img src='//placehold.it/100x100/0bf'>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", movieTemplate);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addNewMovie()">ADD NEW MOVIE</button>
```

...cleaner, nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `<br>` after the picture, try doing it like this:

```
newDiv2.innerHTML = pic + br + text2;

document.body.appendChild(newDiv2);
```